# display: inline-block not working unless first div floated:left

Tags: html, css

I am a relative novice in the world of CSS so please excuse my ignorance! I am attempting to use the following CSS to align two divs horizontally:

```
.portrait {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
 }

.portraitDetails {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 830px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
 }
```

Unfortunately, unless I remove the `display: inline-block` from the `.portrait` class and replace it with `float:left` the `.portraitDetails` div block appears underneath the first div block. What on earth is going on?

Comment: What is the CSS for the parent container of the two divs? Does it have `width: 980px`?

Comment: The width of the container is 1000px but I reduced the width to 980px account for padding.

Comment: Even if I have the width of the second block set to a smaller number of pixels it still appears underneath.

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle for this? According to what you say, everything should work fine. You could also show the CSS for the parent container.

Comment: here's my test site url...http://www.robtest.org.uk/ministry_team.html

Comment: @Dougie - It's best to use a site like jsfiddle.net and create a pared-down version of what you need. When you just provide a full site, it's difficult to tell what's behaving properly and what isn't, since we don't know your site or its intended look.

Comment: @Shauna Thanks for that. Next time I'll try and work out how to use jsfiddle.net :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you provided a working example, the problem seems to be more clear now.
What you have to do is simply remove `display: inline-block` and `width: 830px` properties from the right div. Of course remember to NOT add the `float` property to it.

People sometimes forget what is the purpose of the `float` property. In your case it is the image which should have `float` property and the image only. The right div will remain `100%` wide by default while the image will float it from the left.

*HINT: If the text from the div is long enough to float underneath the image and you want to keep it "indented" at the same point then add the margin to the div with a value equal to the image's width.*

Comment: You, my friend, are a legend! Float is now working properly and I actually understand it! Well, that's one out of two layout issues sorted today! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `display: inline-block;` is that the siblings having this property are always separated by a single white-space **but** only if there are any white-spaces between their *opening* and *closing* tags.
If the parent container has fixed width equal to the sum of the widths of these two divs, then they won't fit because this tiny white-space pushes the second div to the next line. You have to remove the white-space between the tags.
So, **instead of that**:

```
<div class="portrait">
    ...
</div>
<div class="portraitDetails">
    ...
</div>
```

**you have to do that**:

```
<div class="portrait">
    ...
</div><div class="portraitDetails"> <!-- NO SPACE between those two -->
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Or you could use a negative margin `.portrait, .portraitDetails { margin-right: -4px; }`

Comment: @LinkinTED what if the `font-size` of the container is set to some huge value? Then `4px` of negative margin would be not enough I guess.

Comment: Thanks! That appears to work (if I add vertical-align: top) but the html now looks kinda messy. Is there a way to sort this without having to squash up the html? Or is it better just to float the first element and use display: inline-block to position the second div?

Comment: Okay, if i use margin-right: -9px to account for the 5px padding that seems to work. But my question remains, I had read that using in-line block instead of float was the way to go but in this case it seems a bit of a hack... Inline-block works great on the second div because I don't have to specify left starting position for second floating div. But is there any other reason not to use float here?